# Changing parent css on child focus (without breaking parent:hover css rules)

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I made a menu on html (on the side and 100% heigth, expandeable as in android holo)

```
<div id="menu">
<button class="menubutton"></button>
<button class="menubutton"></button>
</div>
```

The menu normally remains transparent and with a short width:

```
#menu {
background-color: transparent;
width: 8%;
}
```

The idea was to expand and color it on hover. It was easy:

```
#menu:hover {
background-color: blue;
width: 90%;
}
```

There is no problem untill here. I need the same effect on  focus. There is no way in css to change parent css on child focus (neither hover by the way, but it is not needed, cuase i can use the entire menu hover).
So i used a script:

```
var menubuttonfocus = document.getElementsByClassName("menubutton");
  for (i=0; i<menubuttonfocus.length; i++) {
    menubuttonfocus[i].addEventListener("focus", function() {
      menu.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      menu.style.width = "90%";
    });
    menubuttonfocus[i].addEventListener("blur", function() {
      menu.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
      menu.style.width = "8%";
    });
  }
```

The script works just fine, the problem is that when you trigger those events by focusing a button, the css of #menu:hover changes somehow and #menu does not change when hovering. I tried to solve this by doing something similar but with hover instead of focus:

```
menu.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
      menu.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      menu.style.width = "90%";
  });
  menu.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
      menu.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
      menu.style.width = "8%";
  });
```

This works somehow, but it is REALLY buggy.
I tried also to select "#menu:hover,#menu:focus", but it doesn't work because the focus is on the button elements and not in #menu.
Please avoid jquery if posible, and i know it's asking for too much but a pure css solution would be awesome.
Probably helpful info: html element are created dinamically with javascript.
I can show more code or screenshot, you can even download it (it is a chrome app) if needed: [chrome webstore page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/idmepniccpokcoohkgjhfinjhpldkopk/)
Thanks.

SOLVED: I did what @GCyrillus told me, changing #menu class on focus via javascript eventListener. .buttonbeingfocused contains the same css as "#menu:hover". Here is the script:

```
var menubuttonfocus = document.getElementsByClassName("menubutton");
  for (i=0; i<menubuttonfocus.length; i++) {
    menubuttonfocus[i].addEventListener("focus", function() {
      menu.classList.add("buttonbeingfocused");
    });
    menubuttonfocus[i].addEventListener("blur", function() {
      menu.classList.remove("buttonbeingfocused");
    });
  }
```

Comment: use add/remove class instead of editing css rules. CSS rule injected via javascript remain and overwrite the rule in your style sheet

Comment: in which case? hovering or focusing? or both?

Comment: Done in focusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the problem is what I think it is - you forgetting about one thing:
When you focusing / mouseentering the `.menubutton` - you are mouseleaving `#menu` and vice-versa - so your menu behaviour is unpredictible because you want to show your menu and hide it at the same time.

solution is usually setting some timeout before running "hiding" part of the script, and clearing this timeout (if exist) when running "showing" part.

it will be something like this:

```
var menuTimeout;

    function showMenu() {
      if (menuTimeout) clearTimeout(menuTimeout);
      menu.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      menu.style.width = "90%";
    }

    function hideMenu() {
      menuTimeout = setTimeout( function() {
        menu.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        menu.style.width = "8%";
      }, 800);
    }

//then add your listeners like you did - but put these functions as a handlers - like this:
menu.addEventListener("mouseenter", showMenu);
...
//in addition you need also "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events handled on .menubuttons
```